# Can I use another selector for jQuery’s ready function?

Tags: jquery, dom

Can I use a selector for the `ready` function other than `document`?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    …
});
```

Comment: what else would you like to be ready? http://api.jquery.com/ready/ it is designed for document according to the docs

Comment: Take a look at the jquery [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) maybe it helps you.

Comment: This has the look of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're trying to do Y (use `ready` on something else than `document`) because X. Edit your question to provide X.